# Where can I find T611 and T612 parts of SQL standard (they both are related to OLAP)?

Tags: sql, specifications

I've tried to find them in sql 2003 standard, downloaded from http://www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip , but it seems that there're only references in text to these items there.

Can anyone suggest any source or a way to get these standards?

Answer (score 2):

A paper on the then proposed OLAP Amendment: *Introduction to OLAP functions* by Fred Zemke, Krishna Kulkarni, Andy Witkowski, and Bob Lyle can be found [here](ftp://ftp.iks-jena.de/pub/mitarb/lutz/standards/sql/OLAP-99-154r2.pdf).

> We propose two Features, T611, “Elementary OLAP functions” and T612,
>   “Advanced OLAP functions”. The elementary feature contains most of the
>   functionality discussed above; latter feature includes
>
> - the WINDOW clause, and
> - Moving or cumulative OLAP functions that specify DISTINCT.